# Rename fields with same name in SPARK

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm consuming a JSON which has the same field names. How I can rename in spark dataframe. please help.

> `val df1 =dataframe.select( "BusinessAsset.Name", "BusinessAsset.Code", "BusinessOperation.Name" as Name1, "BusinessOperation.Code" as code1, "Measurement.RecordedBy.System", "Measurement.RecordedBy.Code" as c1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.select()` can also take the `Column` type, instead of just strings. The `Column` type can have it's name set with it's `.as()` method:

```
val df1 = dataframe.select(
  $"BusinessAsset.Name",
  $"BusinessAsset.Code",
  $"BusinessOperation.Name".as("Name1"),
  $"BusinessOperation.Code".as("code1"),
  $"Measurement.RecordedBy.System",
  $"Measurement.RecordedBy.Code".as("c1")
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Its same like create alias in SQL . That something you can use it